# Paypal Pro - Billing Address state_province & country not being passed

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, paypal

I've been trying to understand how Civicrm uses Paypal as a processor by comparing Pro vs Standard and found something that I think is a bug.

I have a fresh install of Drupal 7.58 & Civicrm 4.7.31 and went straight to setting up a new Paypal Pro processor with a test account and a new event with a registration fee.  When I go to register, I get the following error once I 'continue' past the confirmation screen.

> Notice: Undefined index: state_province in
>   CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalImpl -> doDirectPayment() (line 504 of /homepages/11/d387181311/htdocs/paypal_test/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalImpl.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: country in
>   CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalImpl -> doDirectPayment() (line 505 of /homepages/11/d387181311/htdocs/paypal_test/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalImpl.php).

On the confirmation screen, I can see the 'State' & 'Country' in the Name and Billing Section..  but, for some reason the values are not being passed/picked up when submitting the form.  I also 'hard-coded' my State & Country in the PayPalImpl.php file and as expected, the errors went away.  Even after that, I still keep getting the error

> Security error Security header is not valid

but, this might be for another thread.

Can anyone help me out on this?  I've searched around but I haven't had any luck on something this specific.

Thank you in advance